# Days between two dates with condition for blank input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following formula which output is quite simple, I want the number of days between two dates. It however needs to account for blanks and avoid a negative result. The logic is:

> FORMULA = IF(((DATE A - DATE B))<0,BLANK(),(DATE A - DATE B))

Now I have another thing I would like to introduce:

Is it possible if DATE B is blank, that the formula automatic introduce a new column, lets call that Date C?

So in short days between A and B, but if B is blank use days between A and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ISBLANK` function to check the B value and then reference the C value instead:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B7),IF(A7-C7<0,"",A7-C7),IF(A7-B7<0,"",A7-B7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this function to calculate the date if cell is blank then calculate the other cell.

```
=IF(A7="",C7-B7,IF(B7="",C7-A7,IF(C7="",B7-A7,C7-A7)))
```